# list elements can be edited only the day they are created

Tags: list

I have a list and its elements should only be modified the day they got added.
So, If for example I insert an item today it shouldn't be edited tomorrow.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably do it with an event receiver or workflow or scheduled PowerShell script, that waits until the next day, copies it over to a secondary list where everyone has read access, then deletes the original.

If that isn't desired, then an event receiver or workflow or Powershell scripts sets item level permissions to Read. This could cause real performance problems though.

If that isn't desired, then an event receiver/workflow/PS script could potentially move it into a read only folder on the list. To do this, you have to enable content types on the list, add Folder, then break permissions on the folder to be read for all the users.

Another possible solution would be to use information management policies to declare the item a record so it can't be changed (I've never tested this against list items).

In all of these cases, it would have to run under impersonation or a privileged account to move it into the read only location.